# How to change theme colors in ubuntu MATE

Tags: themes, mate

I remember that 2 weeks ago that I customized my Ubuntu MATE 18.04.4 installation to be darker and also feature a blue color. It's 2 weeks later, I've reinstalled the OS, and I can't figure out how I did it. I remember choosing a theme called like "Ambiant-MATE-blue" or something like that (I don't remember perfectly). I'm one of those people who wants everything to be perfect and this really bugs me. So if anyone can help me with this question, it's going to be great.

Comment: The `mate-appearance-properties` should help.

Comment: open the welcome app . there is an option to customize. something called colors ...